# How Can I Access RUBYMOTION_ENV in an Objective-C category

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Anybody know how I can access the RUBYMOTION_ENV constant in an Objective C category that I'm writing to my vendor directory?

Just now I'm getting

`use of undeclared identifier 'RUBYMOTION_ENV'`

```
#import "NSDate+SecsIn25Mins.h"

@implementation NSDate (SecsIn25Mins)

+ (int) secsIn25Mins {
  return RUBYMOTION_ENV == @"development" ? 10 : 1500;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method which is defined in Ruby from Objective-C.
If you defined the method which return RUBYMOTION_ENV value,
you can retrieve it in Objective-C.

Ruby code:

```
class RubyMotion
  def self.env
    RUBYMOTION_ENV
  end
end
```

Objective-C code:

```
id RubyMotion = NSClassFromString(@"RubyMotion");
NSLog(@"%@", [RubyMotion performSelector:@selector(env)]);
```